# validating a jDateChooser

Tags: java, swing, jdatechooser

I have a jFrame in my java application which inserts the selected date into the database. I want to validate if field is empty.

The code is like this:

```
if(!this.jtxtDate.getSelectedItem.toString().isEmpty()) {
    idc.setDate(this.jtxtDate.getDate);
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "pls choose date");
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Is your `JDateChooser` a third party component? If so which library?

Answer (score 1):

dateChooser.setEnabled(false);

dateChooser.getCalendarButton().setEnabled(true);

So you can't edit the textfield integrated to the JDateChooser.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code inside try block:

```
if(
    ((JTextField)jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText().isEmpty()
) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Date should be filled");
} else {
    //some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just check if you can get date from jDateChooser.

```
if(this.jtxtDate.getDate() != null) {
    idc.setDate(this.jtxtDate.getDate);
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "pls choose date");
}
```