# How to validate JDateChooser in swing application?

Tags: java, swing, jcalendar, jdatechooser

I'm trying to validate `JDateChooser` in my swing application.
How can I validate my date column before submitting my details to the database.(It has to check whether the date column is filled or not).

Comment: Could you post a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please ?

Comment: See also [*Validating Input*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification).

Comment: I answered similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007738/validating-a-jdatechooser/43837726#43837726